# How do I convert etherchain gasnow api data to USD?

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js

The API endpoint is: https://etherchain.org/api/gasnow
And a typical response is:
{
"code": 200,
"data": {
"rapid": 25455811243,
"fast": 22752911470,
"standard": 11000000000,
"priceUSD": 3035.06,
}
}
So how can I convert those rapid, fast, or standard values to an estimated USD cost.
Also: I am just trying to show an estimated gas cost for ETH on a website so if anyone has a different API/way to accomplish this that would work.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

These are prices per gas unit in wei.

A regular transaction to a non-contract address costs 21 thousand gas units.

So with the "rapid" example of 25455811243 wei per gas unit, that's 534572036103000 wei (or ~0.00053 ETH) for a regular transaction. Multiplied by the 3035.06 USD per 1 ETH, that rounds to $1.62.